# How to create a Navigation Tab Item that isn't based on an Object record list

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, custom-reports

How do you go about creating something that you can make a navigation menu item that isn't based on Object lists? I need to create something that would generate some custom reports (default Reports aren't robust enough to handle what I need to do). Basically, I need to allow a user to input some variables and then click a button that would generate a report that displays a bunch of different numbers and graphs related to the many different parts to my DB schema.

I have recently dug into web components, and see great potential in being able to do so, but wasn't for sure if you can make a Web Component a Navigation Tab Item in an App.

Can you do such a thing with Web Components, or is this more in line with Visualforce Pages, or what is the best method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but wasn't for sure if you can make a Web Component a Navigation Tab Item in an App.

You cannot directly make a Lighting Web Component a Navigation Tab Item, but you can always put Lightning Web Components in a Tab and utilize that within your application.

For this, the approach will be:

1. Create an [App Page as described in this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_app_builder/lightning_app_builder_apphome) from Lightning App Builder
2. Put your LWCs on that App Page
3. Include the App Page in your application

You can find a working sample of this approach on the [lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes).